# My overwrite in shared preferences variable doesn't work everytime it goes to if body and not to else body

Tags: android

[!My overwrite in my second class of shared preferences variable doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77TAv.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77TAv.jpg)

Comment: My main activity code is:

Comment: My main activity code is:    sp1=getSharedPreferences("shareddata2", 0);  SharedPreferences.Editor editor1=sp.edit();                        editor1.putInt("jm2",0);                                                          editor1.commit();

Comment: It doesnt show any error bt during second time when i come back to second activity from third activity it should go to else body bt it goes again to if body the value always remain 0 for jm2

Comment: You are conscious that you are filling 2 sharedpreferences files, right? shareddata1 and shareddata2